# Trying to copy schema's from one cluster to another using Postgres 12dot12 using S3 and unable to export the schema's

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, import, export

Trying to copy schema's from one cluster to another using Postgres 12dot12 using S3 and unable to export the schema's.

Only tables are gettting exported and I need to pick each table to be exported. Just imagine I have 20 schema's and average of 20 tables in each schema, which is a pain to export tables indivially.

It's only allowed to export tables and not functions / procedures / triggers / indexes and other objects.

Any help with the steps to export this would be really appreciated.

We have tried exporting schema's to S3 bucket and it's only allowed us to export tables individually for each schema.
I have tried exporting this to local drive and it worked successfully.

We want to use S3 bucket to export and not local drives.